# Autoload libraries in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, autoload

I am a newbie to Codeigniter.
 I have 3 libraries in autoload in `config.php` .

But in one of my controllers I don't want to load the libraries. Is this possible?

Comment: It is bit tricky thing to do, becouse autoload is global function. Take a look at this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096630/not-to-load-an-autoload-library-in-codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096630/not-to-load-an-autoload-library-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Extend CI_Controller in your libraries.**

**Something like this:**

```
class MyLibrary extends CI_Controller {
    var $ci;

    function __construct() {

      $this->ci = &get_instance();
      $route = $this->ci->router->fetch_class();

      if( $route == strtolower('YourController') ) return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need any library throughout the application you can load it in the config file and it will be auto loaded. But if you need a library only in a specific controller you can load it in the controller where you need it.

```
Class test Extends CI_Controller{

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('mylibrary');
        $this->mylibrary->somemethod();    
    }

}
```

Or if you need library through out the controller you can load it in the constructor.

```
Class test Extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
         $this->load->library('mylibrary');
    }

    function index(){
         $this->mylibrary->somemethod();    
    }
    function test(){
         $this->mylibrary->someothermethod();    
    }

}
```

Comment: Does loading models in constructor really work? Never tried it this way... Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove libraries from autoload file. then they will not be activ in the framwork.
If you want to use them, you can call them in constructors if you want them in a class. If you want to use them in just method, you load them in the method.