# Codeigniter: Change autoload libraries for one controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoload

I've the following libs in the `autoload.php`:

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');`

I need the session lib everywhere - besides of ONE controller, where it causes only trouble. Now the question is:

Is there a possibility NOT to load the session lib for this special controller or is the only option to delete it from the autoload and add it to every single controller, where needed?

Comment: I would rather fix that **one** problem instead of messing with autoload...

Answer (score 4):

In your autoload.php:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

$CI =& get_instance();
if ($CI->router->fetch_class()!='conflictingcontroller') array_push($autoload['libraries'], 'session');
```

Comment: Haven't tested it as I've already made the 'long' version, but if it's works its very nice. Thx. Will it try later.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from this answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8099827/2471423)

> Autoloading is meant for site-global items.
>
> A cleaner solution may be to extend the controller and load the
>   library in that new controller's constructor. Then all of your
>   controllers extend from that controller, except the one(s) you don't
>   want to load that library - those can extend the original CI
>   controller.
>
> That should take you < 5 minutes to implement and you won't have to
>   hack anything.

However since it is a `session` and not `database` or `uri` helpers, Kumar's answer may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below in your controller constructor

```
$this->session = null;
```

or

```
unset($this->session);
```

Comment: But when it loads there are already made DB inserts/updates on the sessions table, right? This I want to avoid for this controller as is locks the DB.

Comment: Are you storing session in table?

Comment: Sure.. otherwise they wouldn't lock the tables. ^^

Comment: If you are not using session in that particular controller, then you can unset.